# Problems with VS code and C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am having some problems with VS code and C#. When I try to compile via F5 or run button on VSC it gives me this error:

```
>scriptcs : The term 'scriptcs' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1
'+ scriptcs -info
>'+ ~~~~~~~~
  >  "+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (scriptcs:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  >  "+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

So I have been dealing with this problem for some weeks and nothing. I tried installing scriptCS, which I read helps, but it doesn't. I reinstalled dotnet core, which also didn't help. Also reinstalled my C# extensions - didn't work. I am thinking to reinstall VS code and see what happens. Maybe someone here has solved this problem or I am too blind to see the answer.

Comment: Jason did u find a solution, if yes, please do let me now.

Comment: I deleted everything connected to VS and .NET, installed it again, and worked.